Dropdown option not being set when changing my DropdownSection component
I have a Link dropdown which changes a DropdownSection component which contains an array of options.
When I change to a different Link, I would like to set the default option of the DropdownSection to the second option if there is more than one option in the linkOptions array, as I don't want to select the first "No Selection" option. E.g. if I select Link 2, it should select the "Three" option.
Currently, when I select a value in the DropdownSection and then change the Link dropdown, the selected option is blank.
E.g. Upon loading the app. Link 1 is the default selected Link dropdown:

After selecting the Link 2 option in the Link dropdown:

Example code of how I set the default option (using a component that wraps a React Fluent UI Dropdown component):
<DropdownSection
  label={linkOptions[0].text}
  options={link1Options}
  defaultOptionText={link1Options.length > 1 ? link1Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
  defaultOptionValue={link1Options.length > 1 ? link1Options[1].value : "0"}
/>

App:
const App = ({}) => {
  const linkOptions = [
    {
      text: "Link 1",
      value: "1",
    },
    {
      text: "Link 2",
      value: "2",
    },
    {
      text: "Link 3",
      value: "3",
    },
  ];

  const [link, setLink] = useState(linkOptions[0].value);

  const link1Options = [
    {
      text: "No Selection",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      text: "One",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      text: "Two",
      value: "2"
    },
  ];
  const link2Options = [
    {
      text: "No Selection",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      text: "Three",
      value: "3"
    },
    {
      text: "Four",
      value: "4"
    },
  ];
  const link3Options = [
    {
      text: "No Selection",
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      text: "Five",
      value: "5"
    },
    {
      text: "Six",
      value: "6"
    },
  ];

  let linkDropdownSection = <></>;
  if (link === linkOptions[0].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[0].text}
        options={link1Options}
        defaultOptionText={link1Options.length > 1 ? link1Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={link1Options.length > 1 ? link1Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  } else if (link === linkOptions[1].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[1].text}
        options={link2Options}
        defaultOptionText={link2Options.length > 1 ? link2Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={link2Options.length > 1 ? link2Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  } else if (link === linkOptions[2].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[2].text}
        options={link3Options}
        defaultOptionText={link3Options.length > 1 ? link3Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={link3Options.length > 1 ? link3Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  }

  // @ts-ignore: next-line - Ignore event parameter
  const onLinkSelect: DropdownProps["onOptionSelect"] = (event: any, data: any) => {
    setLink(data.optionValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        {
          <section>
            <Dropdown
              defaultValue={linkOptions[0].text}
              defaultSelectedOptions={[linkOptions[0].value]}
              onOptionSelect={onLinkSelect}
            >
              {linkOptions.map((option) => (
                <Option key={`${optionId}-${option.value}`} value={option.value}>
                  {option.text}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Dropdown>
            {linkDropdownSection}
          </section>
        }
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

DropdownSection:
const DropdownSection = ({
  label,
  options,
  defaultOptionText,
  defaultOptionValue,
}) => {
  const optionId = useId("option");

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <Label>{label}</Label>
        <Dropdown
          defaultValue={defaultOptionText}
          defaultSelectedOptions={[defaultOptionValue]}
          onOptionSelect={onContactSelect}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <FluentUIOption key={`${optionId}-${option.value}`} value={option.value}>
              {option.text}
            </FluentUIOption>
          ))}
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
      <Divider />
    </section>
  );
};

You can see onLinkSelect is responsible for changing the Link dropdown as it calls setLink.

Try wrapping the following code into a useMemo:
let linkDropdownSection = <></>;
  if (link === linkOptions[0].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[0].text}
        options={item1Options}
        defaultOptionText={item1Options.length > 1 ? item1Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={item1Options.length > 1 ? item1Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  } else if (link === linkOptions[1].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[1].text}
        options={item2Options}
        defaultOptionText={item2Options.length > 1 ? item2Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={item2Options.length > 1 ? item2Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  } else if (link === linkOptions[2].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[2].text}
        options={item3Options}
        defaultOptionText={item3Options.length > 1 ? item3Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={item3Options.length > 1 ? item3Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  }

and passing the value of your first dropdown to the dependency array. e.g.
const componentRender = useMemo(() => {
  let linkDropdownSection = <></>;
  if (link === linkOptions[0].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[0].text}
        options={item1Options}
        defaultOptionText={item1Options.length > 1 ? item1Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={item1Options.length > 1 ? item1Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  } else if (link === linkOptions[1].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[1].text}
        options={item2Options}
        defaultOptionText={item2Options.length > 1 ? item2Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={item2Options.length > 1 ? item2Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  } else if (link === linkOptions[2].value) {
    linkDropdownSection = (
      <DropdownSection
        label={linkOptions[2].text}
        options={item3Options}
        defaultOptionText={item3Options.length > 1 ? item3Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
        defaultOptionValue={item3Options.length > 1 ? item3Options[1].value : "0"}
      />
    );
  }

return linkDropdownSelection;
}, [link])


EDIT:

const dropdown = useMemo(() => {

  let resp =  {
     label: '',
     options: [],
     defaultText: 'No Selection',
     defaultValue: '0'
  }

  if (link === linkOptions[0].value) {
    resp.label = linkOptions[0].text;
    resp.options = item10Options;
    
  } else if (link === linkOptions[1].value) {

    resp.label = linkOptions[1].text;
    resp.options = item2Options;

 
  } else if (link === linkOptions[2].value) {
     resp.label = linkOptions[2].text;
     resp.options = item3Options;
  }

return resp;
}, [link]);


<DropdownSection
   label={dropdown.label}
   options={dropdown.options}
   defaultOptionText={dropdown.defaultText}
   defaultOptionValue={defaultValue}
/>


I used this code then replaced the {linkDropdownSection} with {componentRender} in the App component. Unfortunately it did not work for me.

can you create a useEffect and console log the change to link, just to ensure that is getting correctly set?

When I add React.useEffect(() => { console.log(link); }, []); below where I declare the state variable const [link, setLink] = useState(linkOptions[0].value);, on load it writes 1 twice. When I change the link, it doesn't log anything.

Need to add link into the dependency array for it to log changes. Like so: React.useEffect(() => { console.log(link); }, [link]);

Thank you, I did that change and now I see on load it writes 1 like before. When I change the link from Link 1 to Link 2, it writes 2, which seems correct.

Cool so your link variable is definitely getting set, can you add a console log to the top of your useMemo with the value of link to ensure the useMemo is being triggered.

Like this? const componentRender = React.useMemo(() => { console.log("componentRender", link); ... }, [link]); It writes componentRender 1 twice on load, then it writes componentRender 2 twice when I change to Link 2.

Probably the next thing to try is in the use memo instead of returning the comonent return an object with the following keys: {label: "label", options: [], defaultText: 'dt', defaultValue: 'dv'}, then in your render, use the memoized values of that in your 

I've updated my answer with an example.

Unfortunately this did not work - it preserves the value that was selected in the previous LinkDropdownSection, after selecting a different Link. I also added resp.defaultOptionText = linkXOptions.length > 1 ? linkXOptions[1].text : "No Selection"; resp.defaultOptionValue = linkXOptions.length > 1 ? linkXOptions[1].value : "0"; in the if statements to match the previous code (where X is the link number) - this reproduced my original issue.

Hmm i wonder that useId thing you have, what is that? Maybe because the id isn't changing its not refreshing the results? can you try without that and just use the id of the option or something

I removed the optionId in the option key so it is only using option.value. That didn't seem to do anything, although it was definitely a good spot. useId just generates a unique ID or string.

Okay next plan, do a json dump in your dropdown section component to see if its getting updated values.

I added these lines console.log("defaultOptionText", defaultOptionText); console.log("defaultOptionValue", defaultOptionValue);. On load, it says No Selection and 0, which is what I see in the dropdown as well, so that's correct. When selecting a different option, e.g. One, then switch the Link, it still says One as the default option. The console writes No Selection and 0 which is actually correct, but the option text does not match the console logs.

If you console log the options in the component does it change?

On load, Link 1 is selected:
0: {text: 'No Selection', value: '0'} 1: {text: 'One', value: '1'} 2: {text: 'Two', value: '2'}
When switching to Link 2:
0: {text: 'No Selection', value: '0'} 1: {text: 'Three', value: '3'} 2: {text: 'Four', value: '4'}
These options seem to be set correctly when switching Links, even when selecting an option in the Link options dropdown before switching to another Link.

What is the <Dropdown component you are using, is it from a library?

Yes, it's fluentui/react-components. This is the link to the docs for this component: https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/components-dropdown--default

The props defaultValue and defaultSelectedOptions only set the initial state for the dropdown. In your case the problem is that in the code it looks like the <DropdownSection>'s are different components, but for react it is basically the same component (same type of component in the same place). So actually by changing the first dropdown, you don't 'replace' the <DropdownSection>, you only change the props for that component. That means that the state of the component is also preserved and therefore the change of defaultValue and defaultSelectedOptions has no effect.
To solve that issue, you simply have to give react a way to distinguish the different <DropdownSection>'s by adding a unique key to them:
<DropdownSection
  key={linkOptions[0].value}
  label={linkOptions[0].text}
  options={link1Options}
  defaultOptionText={link1Options.length > 1 ? link1Options[1].text : "No Selection"}
  defaultOptionValue={link1Options.length > 1 ? link1Options[1].value : "0"}
/>

As a result, changing the first dropdown also changes the key of the component, which causes react to mount the DropdownSection as a new component and defaultValue and defaultSelectedOptions work like expected.
